# show/hide div with active links issue

Tags: jquery

I have three menu with their respective content. Now problem is when I switch from "Menu One" to "Menu Two" you will notice "Menu One" content div remain open. Please guide me how can I open only one content div at a time? Also menu needs to be active only when it's content open.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/jubsr5hd/)

HTML:

```
<span class="link1">Menu One</span>
<span class="link2">Menu Two</span>
<span class="link3">Menu Three</span>

<div id="div1">Menu One</div>
<div id="div2">Menu Two</div>
<div id="div3">Menu Three</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".link1").on('click', function (event)  {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("#div1").slideToggle()("fast")
});
$(".link2").on('click', function (event)  {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("#div2").slideToggle()("fast")
});
$(".link3").on('click', function (event)  {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("#div3").slideToggle()("fast")
});
});
```

Comment: You have 3 good answers below, any feedback? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

**HTML**:

```
<span class="link" name="menu1">Menu One</span>
<span class="link" name="menu2">Menu Two</span>
<span class="link" name="menu3">Menu Three</span>

<div class="submenu" name="menu1">Menu One</div>
<div class="submenu" name="menu2">Menu Two</div>
<div class="submenu" name="menu3">Menu Three</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
span{display:inline-block; padding:10px; cursor:pointer;}
.active{color:#fff; background:red;}
div{display:none; background:red; height:80px; color:#fff; text-align:center; line-height:80px; font-size:20px;}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".link").on('click', function (event)  {
    Toggle($(this));
});

function Toggle(obj){
    var submenu = $(".submenu[name="+obj.attr('name')+"]");
    $(".submenu").not(submenu).hide();
    $(".link").not(obj).removeClass('active');
    submenu.slideToggle("fast");
    obj.toggleClass('active');
}
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jubsr5hd/11/) to see how it works.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Perfect, the best thing is I can hide the container by clicking the tab again. Great Thanks Dude :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link1").on('click', function (event)  {
        $(".link2").removeClass("active");$("#div2").hide();
        $(".link3").removeClass("active");$("#div3").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $("#div1").slideToggle()("fast")
    });
    $(".link2").on('click', function (event)  {
        $(".link1").removeClass("active");$("#div1").hide();
        $(".link3").removeClass("active");$("#div3").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $("#div2").slideToggle()("fast");
    });
    $(".link3").on('click', function (event)  {
        $(".link1").removeClass("active");$("#div1").hide();
        $(".link2").removeClass("active");$("#div2").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $("#div3").slideToggle()("fast")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way...

Here is my JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jubsr5hd/3/

Here is my CSS

```
span{display:inline-block; padding:10px; cursor:pointer;}
.active{color:#fff; background:red;}
div{display:none; background:red; height:80px; color:#fff; text-align:center; line-height:80px; font-size:20px;}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<span class="link1" target="div1">Menu One</span>
<span class="link2" target="div2">Menu Two</span>
<span class="link3" target="div3">Menu Three</span>

<div id="div1">Menu One</div>
<div id="div2">Menu Two</div>
<div id="div3">Menu Three</div>
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[class*="link"]').on('click', function (event)  {
        var myTarget = $(this).attr("target");
        hideRemove();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('[id="'+myTarget+'"]').slideToggle()("fast");
    });

    function hideRemove() {
        $('[class*="link"]').removeClass('active');
        $('[id*="div"]').removeAttr('style');
    }

});
```